# Ios 6 news feed (hidden page)

Tags: objective-c, ios5, storyboard

I want to create a hidden page on top of main screen (like iOS 6 news feed) and a button at the top-right corner. When people push it or hold it and swipe toward downside, the hidden menu will appear.  Honestly I don't have any idea about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have more complex events than just a tap on a button you should be looking at using a `UIGestureRecognizer`. For the types of interactions you're describing you will likely need 2 recognizers - `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` for the tap and hold, and then a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` for the downwards swipe. You might be able to use a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` rather than the pan but I'm not sure if a swipe needs to start with an independent tap from the long press.

Good resources for learning about gestures are:

- [Gesture Recognizer Basics - Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW2)
- [UIGestureRecognizer Tutorial from raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more)